# Как в Android Studio (Debian) поставить шрифты как в Windows?

Tags: android-studio, debian

Как в Android Studio в Debian, установить шрифты, как в Windows? В версии для Windows шрифты были гладкими, сглаженными, а в Debian-версии - ровные, вытянутые и некрасивые :D. Настойки из версии для Windows я импортировал в Linux-версию, но не помогло...

---

Код сейчас выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно так (старое фото, так что качество не очень..):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

У меня Android Studio 2.1.1, Debian 8 Jessie + LXDE + OpenBox.

Comment: Поставьте Windows. И двадцать лет назад не было нормальных шрифтов, сейчас нет, и никогда не будет. Так бы может и сам на линух перешёл, но шрифты всё портят.

Comment: В настройках студии пробовали изменять шрифты для редактора?

Comment: @qwerty123, да, но не вышло сделать такой, как был в Windows. И, как я написал, я уже импортировала шрифты из старой AS. Мне кажется тут проблема в графической оболочке...